# error using EPCTILE to find median using complex survey data in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm trying to calculate median values of a given variable (`fishmonthly` - days per month that a given household eats fish. Must be between 0 and 31.) I've prepared the survey data using `svyset sitecode [pweight= obsweightstratroadsite], strata(onroad)` and I'm trying to calculate median values per village (`sitecode`) using epctile with `epctile fishmonthly, p(50) over(sitecode) svy`. However, any time the median value of `fishmonthly` for a given village is 0, the code fails in the following way in the first stage:

(example output presented for `epctile fishmonthly, p(50) subpop(if sitecode==1) svy`)

```
             |             Linearized
             |       Mean   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
    __000007 |        -.5          .             .           .
--------------------------------------------------------------
estimates post: matrix has missing values
r(504);
```

I've checked my dataset and the variable `fishmonthly` has no missing values.

When the code fails, the 'mean' is almost always returned as "-.p" where p is the percentile requested in the epctile command. (When the code does not fail - i.e. when the real median is not equal to 0, as far as I can tell - the 'mean' is returned in the first stage as a 6 or 7 digit negative number and the second stage reports the correct median.)

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error and how I might fix it?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and have now finally figured it out. It calls error when the first percentile in the data is larger than what you've asked for. E.g. if you asked for p(50), but the lowest value in your data has frequency of 50.1 %, it will give the error. If you ask for for p(50.1), you'll get the estimate. Quite annoying.